# Auto-firing action every Monday ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, scheduled-tasks

I am implementing a system using ASP.NET MVC4. I have an action named 'UpdateStatus'. I want to run this action repeatedly on every Monday. Could I do this without any user interaction?

My Contoller:

```
using PagedList;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public ActionResult UpdateStatus()
{
    //some action here
}
```

Please help!Thanks very much...

Comment: A few options discussed [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Comment: Check out Revalee: http://revalee.sageanalytic.com/

Answer (score 2):

This answer is non-mvc, so may not be what you want, but it could work alongside your mvc code. For me the best way to run code on a schedule is to use windows "Task Scheduler". You get logs of when it ran, if it completed successfully and the ability to easily do ad-hoc runs.

To do this you would add the code in UpdateStatus (and it's dependencies) to a project of type "console application". You'll be able to deploy this to your server and run it as a scheduled task using windows "Task Scheduler". If you've not worked with scheduled tasks before [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/187370/what-is-the-best-way-to-run-a-console-application-once-per-day-at-a-certain-time) should help. You can add command line parameters or a mutex so only one instance ever runs if you need to but it sounds like you may not need those.